Active buzzer PNP transistor
I'm making a project with an Arduino using an active buzzer 5v. I saw many forums with mixed comments about using an active buzzer straight to the I/O pins without any current limiting. Then I also saw this active buzzer module which has a PNP transistor (SMD 2TY) and a 1k resistor (SMD 102) at the base.
Do I really need such a setup/module? I know that the Arduino I/O pins are maxed at 20ma but then I saw videos showing bare buzzer connecting to the I/O pins and everything works. I'm confused.


There's no general rule. It's all about how much individual pins can source/sink, what the MCU can source/sink as whole and how much current you need to draw. 20mA source/sink is some sort of industry standard maxium though and it will be rare to find an MCU that can handle more than that directly on the pins.

So it will be a good idea to use the module instead of directly connecting the buzzer to the I/O pins?

No idea, what's your use-case? How much current does the buzzer draw? Are you sure that the PWM pins which I suppose will be used here can source 20mA? Do you need to source other things (LEDs etc) from other MCU pins as well?

Just making it beep beep like an alarm. Don't need tones or fancy tunes. Just need Digital HIGH and LOW for 200 millisecond delay loops. No other components. I don't know the current draw or datasheets. It's Adafruit 5v breadboard friendly active buzzer, no datasheet were there. I tried with multimeter current mode for 200mA and the buzzer won't work. Tried 10A mode and the buzzer beeps and the value is 0.1A. I don't trust it.

No datasheet = no deal. And it sounds like you've blown the 200mA fuse of your multimeter. However, I'm assuming this part is meant to be used with PWM, so if you just short the base of the transistor I'm not sure if that current reading is adequate. (Also I think PNP is an odd choice here logic-wise)

I think they used PNP for low level trigger.

Isn't Arduino always 5V?

@Lundin -- Arduino is not always 5V. Arduino Fio is 3.3V, [according to this Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems}. In addition, according to this Arduino page, some Nano boards can be powered directly with 3.3 V.

Actually, Atmega328 pins are allowed to handle upto 40mA of current each (both for sourcing and sinking). But there is still a question how much your buzzer consumes? I've just checked three active buzzers I have. Two were drawing ca. 10mA at 5V. But the third one took almost 40mA!
So if you're sure that you don't exceed any limits you can connect the buzzer directly to your MCU pin. But using a transistor is not a bad idea at all.
